# Fatal error: Class 'Adminmodule_Customerpage_Helper_Data' not found in /home/weburl/app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: admin-panel, fatal-error

This Error occured durring **instalation** of **extension** in magento store.
when i did configuration disable and copmlitaion enabled, then all dashbord of admnin pannel lost and this error showing on my admin pannel.
Please advice me how i can recover my website from this error.  [image]

Comment: Thank you dears for helping me. I can try this method to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you share app/code/.../etc/config.xml from this module?

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable compilation. To disable compilation in Magento, edit:-- includes/config.php. At around line 28, uncomment the first line and comment out the second:

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

then after remove the directory var/cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your site compilation is on So follow below solution

**Solution 1:**

Turn Off the compiler from your terminal steps

1. Open your terminal /connect your ssh access
2. Go to your magento root via this command `cd \yourpathtomagentoDir`
3. Fire this commnad  `php -f compiler.php disable`
4. After this do compile `php -f compiler.php compile`
5. After this enable compile `php -f compiler.php enable`

**Solution 2:**

1. Go to your module's xml file located in `app/etc/modules` and disable the module
2. Clear the cache
3. Now you are able to login in back end
4. Disable the compiler and install your module
5. Do compile and enable your magento compile